# "ValueError: x and y must be the same size" with scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm new to Data Analytic
I've been working on the Regression Analysis Coding using matplotlib, numpy and pandas. However, I got some trouble with and try my best to find the way to resolve the problem via Stackoverflow and other websites, still, I could not.

Here's the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

Training_Dataset = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kuroisep/Problem-1-Data-Analytic/main/A-train.csv?token=GHSAT0AAAAAABZ7O6G34ZTK4PMQGGZLRVS4Y2LAJSQ")
Training_Dataset = Training_Dataset.dropna()
X_train = np.array(Training_Dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values) # Independent Variable
y_train = np.array(Training_Dataset.iloc[:, 1].values) # Dependent Variable

Testing_Datatset = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kuroisep/Problem-1-Data-Analytic/main/A-test.csv?token=GHSAT0AAAAAABZ7O6G2PRKTCT6YBKLZZSRWY2LAK2Q")
Testing_Dataset = Testing_Dataset.dropna()
X_test = np.array(Testing_Dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values) # Independent Variable
y_test = np.array(Testing_Dataset.iloc[:, 1].values) # Dependent Variable

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

accuracy = regressor.score(X_test, y_test)
print('Accuracy = '+ str(accuracy))

plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color = 'red', marker = 'o', s = 35, alpha = 0.5,
          label = 'Test data')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue', label='Model Plot')
plt.title('Predicted Values vs Inputs')
plt.xlabel('Inputs')
plt.ylabel('Predicted Values')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()
```

And Here's the Syntax Error Detail

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, **kwargs)
   4389         y = np.ma.ravel(y)
   4390         if x.size != y.size:
-> 4391             raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
   4392 
   4393         if s is None:

ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

my X_test value is (shape = (6,8))

```
array([[-2.474000e+01, -1.550000e+00,  9.105000e+01,  2.401980e+03,
        -1.520000e+00,  1.360000e+01,  5.660000e+00,  1.059000e+01],
       [ 1.075400e+02, -2.869000e+01, -8.259000e+01,  2.578915e+04,
         5.290000e+00, -8.560000e+00,  1.490000e+00, -4.730000e+00],
       [ 4.508000e+01,  9.662000e+01,  5.185000e+01,  1.280000e+00,
         3.580000e+00,  5.200000e-01, -6.860000e+00, -7.800000e-01],
       [-1.228100e+02,  1.779000e+01, -1.828500e+02,  2.928970e+03,
        -1.210000e+00, -2.060000e+00,  9.680000e+00, -8.590000e+00],
       [ 7.761000e+01, -7.230000e+01,  9.728000e+01,  1.917394e+04,
        -9.290000e+00,  8.600000e-01,  7.060000e+00, -8.060000e+00],
       [-4.401000e+01,  1.316500e+02,  6.988000e+01,  1.778310e+03,
        -1.375000e+01, -1.475000e+01, -1.227000e+01, -8.300000e-01]])
```

my y_test value is (shape=(6,))

```
array([ -1.55, -28.69,  96.62,  17.79, -72.3 , 131.65])
```

I'm sorry if my question seems old.
Thank you for your kindness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[plt.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html#matplotlib-pyplot-scatter) requires the x and y points to have the shape of `(n,)`. In your case the shapes of `X_test`, `y_test` are `((6, 8), (6,))`, respectively. Considering the label of the first plot is `Test data`, you can use `np.arange` so that you can get `y_test` values over indexes:

```
plt.scatter(np.arange(len(y_test)), y_test, color = 'red', marker = 'o', s = 35, alpha = 0.5,
      label = 'Test data')
```

Output:

[image]

For the second plot, `regressor.predict(X_train)` will give the predicted `y_train` values so again compare predicted values with actual values:

```
plt.plot(y_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue', label='Model Plot')
```

Output:

[image]

By the way, your train-test split isn't right. You set `x2` as the target variable but `x2` is also included in the `training` set, that is the reason why the model has perfectly fitted and gives `100%` accuracy, but that is the beyond the scope of this question.